# Is there a simple way to use Column Number in "WHERE" SQL statement

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm using SQL statement for the fist time in VBA, how can I use the column number of my Excel sheet in a SQL statement?

Below is an example of what I want to do :

```vb
"SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE 'ColumnNumber4 =" & mySQLVariable
```

As you see the only thing wrong there is 'ColumnNumber4'

I've already tried this :

```vb
"SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE  [M] =" & mySQLVariable
```

Where M is the name I have set for the Column Number 4 but this don't work as excepted : my .docx ask me to select a table but the table MUST be selected with the

```
"SELECT * FROM[Sheet1$] WHERE[M] = " & mySQLVariable
```

NB : `SELECT * FROM[Sheet1$]` work :

The excel file is like this  : [image: Excel file]

Before using the macro the docx looks like :

[image: Before Macro]

and after it looks like this (Working as excepted)

[image: After Macro]

By deduction i think that `WHERE[M] = " & mySQLVariable` is the problem

In fact with WHERE I got :
[image: With WHERE Statment]

Here is my full code  :

```vb
Sub Publipostage()
    'Nécessite d'activer la référence "Microsoft Word xx.x Object Library"
    Dim docWord As Word.Document
    Dim appWord As Word.Application
    Dim NomBase As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rs As Recordset

    i = 3
    mySQLVariable = "MyString"
    NomBase = "M:\User\Folder\FolderItem.xlsm"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set appWord = New Word.Application
    appWord.Visible = True
    'Ouverture du document principal Word
    Set docWord = appWord.Documents.Open("M:\User\Folder\FolderItem.docx")

    MsgBox ActiveCell.Column

    Set rs = "SELECT * FROM [Interface-Test$]"
    Debug.Print rs(3).Name


    'fonctionnalité de publipostage pour le document spécifié
    With docWord.MailMerge
        'Ouvre la base de données
       .OpenDataSource Name:=NomBase, _ Connection:="Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xlsm)};" & _ 
"DBQ=" & NomBase & "; ReadOnly=True; ", _ 
SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM [Interface-Test$] WHERE [F4] = " & mySQLVariable        

'Spécifie la fusion vers l'imprimante
        .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
        .suppressBlankLines = True
            'Prend en compte l'ensemble des enregistrements
            With .DataSource
                .FirstRecord = wdDefaultFirstRecord
                .LastRecord = wdDefaultLastRecord
            End With
        'Exécute l'opération de publipostage
        .Execute Pause:=False
    End With

    ' Activation du doucment principal de Publipostage et fermeture
    docWord.Activate
    docWord.Close savechanges:=False
    ' Affichage l'application Word
    appWord.Visible = True
    Set docWord = Nothing
    Set appWord = Nothing

    'Fermeture du document Word
    'docWord.Close False
    'appWord.Quit
End Sub
```

Thanks for your time and consideration.

Comment: `ActiveCell.Column` will return the column number of selected cell in your 
 active worksheet. May that work for you?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Sure it does work

Comment: @Parfait Done, hope its better like this

Comment: My Excel have named column : "M" Is the name of one column. I added screenshot to make it more visual. Regards @Parfait

Comment: @Parfait i've shown only 1 row data so you know the structure of my excel file. Keep in mind that there is more than 1 row. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: @Parfait juste mail Address, you miss understood [M], is the name i have set for the column C, i know this is strange and i will rename it. In the WHERE statement i want to use the C column

Comment: Whatever you call it, make sure the actual names correspond in SQL. Your main issue is data beginning on `A2`. See below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown finally by OP, the data range of Excel begins on `A2` with column headers in row 2 and data beginning in row 3. In Excel ODBC connections, when specifying `SheetName$`, by default it assumes data begins in `A1` with named columns.

Since this default does not apply, the `FROM` clause must change accordingly to specify the beginning and end cell. To avoid this specific range requirement, adjust spreadsheet to not use row 1 for non-data items.

```
SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM [Interface-Test$A2:P1000] WHERE [MAIL ADDRESS] = " & mySQLVariable
```

Comment: This doesn't work, but it print an error message now : 5922 "Can't access DB"

Comment: Works great on my end using an Excel sheet with data starting at row 2 with named columns and with nearly your same *Publipostage* sub! Possibly zero rows results with that query. If space and special characters are in *mySQLVariable* wrap it with square brackets, `[...]`. Try running without `WHERE` and limit rows with `SELECT TOP 5 * FROM ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little ambiguous but...

If you want to use the column number then you can use [F4] as the identifier.  This is what it will default to.

If you want to use the name of the column you have to be sure to have set HDR=YES in your connection string.

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsx;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES";
```

If you simply want to work out what the name of the fourth column is...

```
set rs="SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"
Debug.Print rs(3).name
```

Which will give you the name the recordset is using (the field numbers start at zero).

Comment: when i want to use your second code it is not working (object required). For the first one can you please explain me where should i put the code into my connection string ?
My actual connection string :                                               `.OpenDataSource Name:=NomBase, _
            Connection:="Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xlsm)};" & _
            "DBQ=" & NomBase & "; ReadOnly=True; ", _
            SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM [Interface-Test$] WHERE [F4] = " & mySQLVariable`

Comment: The second piece of code won't work unless rs is decalred as a Recordset.  It's hard to show you how to implement code unless you provide your code as an example.
To use the connection string you would change the text after Connection="..."

Comment: I just updated my post : at the end of the post you can found my full code

Comment: To use the second piece of code you would use `Debug.Print ThisDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.FieldNames(3)` which would show the header name that the recordset is returning.
To add the connection string to include the headers (so you can refer to them by name) change to `.OpenDataSource Name:=NomBase, _
Connection:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & NomBase & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";", _
SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM [Interface-Test$] WHERE [M] = " & mySQLVariable`

Comment: When i try to use recordset i got the error : Type not compatible. 
I Set : `Dim rs As recordset` i tried also Dim rs As `ADO.recordset` any idea ? Maybe the Library i selected in reference is wrong

Comment: Sorry, but this is hard to explain without going into the full details of Recordsets and I don't think you have enough experience for me to explain.  I think you should have enough to answer the question, but I can't spend more time on this one I'm afraid.

Comment: okay i understand thanks for your help @Gareth, but `.OpenDataSource Name:=NomBase, _ Connection:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & NomBase & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";", _ SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM [Interface-Test$] WHERE [M] = " & mySQLVariable` i have also  tried with F4 But still not working :-(